# Adobe Flash Player keeps wanting me to update it

Tags: flash-player

It seems like I get a notification every week to update Adobe Flash Player.  After it updates, it informs me that it is now version 10.3.  I'm wondering, has it gotten into a situation in which is repeats updating itself and installing the same version over and over again?  Or is it updating version 10.3 by some minor update?

I'm using this on a Windows 7 Ultimate machine and a Windows XP Pro machine.

Comment: Can you check to see what version of Flash Player you have installed?

Comment: What version do you have installed and what version is being reported as being the current version.  Without this information we cannot help.

Comment: Well there seems to have been more flash exploits lately so unless you verify that the flash version before and after an update is the same I'd say it's all in order.

Comment: Before the update, I have version 10.3.  After the update, I have version 10.3.  The notification from Adobe about a "new update" doesn't bother to tell me what version of new update is supposed to be.

Comment: It matters not if you check "Do not remind me about this update" Adobe never honors their "ignore" check boxes. This is not the only Adobe product where I check that box. But next reboot, it's back again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried updating manually? Close all open browsers, then run [these](http://www.filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_ie/) [two](http://www.filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_firefox/) installers. For good measure, reboot after installing.

Answer (score -3):

Next time, when you get the update notification, remember to check the "**Do not remind me about this update**" before closing.

Comment: While this answer does make flash stop nagging him I think it's very bad advice. You should *always* keep your flash player updated.